# Display buttons one at time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
public class HundredButtons extends JFrame {
    public HundredButtons() throws InterruptedException {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.setSize(500,500);

        this.setVisible(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {


            JButton button = new JButton("" + i);
            button.setSize(500/10, 500/10);

            panel.add(button);
            this.add(panel);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(500,500);

            this.setVisible(true);


        }
    }
}
```

Hi im new to this site and programming im trying to start making some gui programs. I have two questions. 1. Is there a way to debugg a gui, when i program i sometimes find it helpful to trace through the code by putting print statement at important locations , I cant seem to debugg gui because it builds the gui all at once. Below is the closest thing i have come to seeing a simple gui build in stages. is there a better wayto do this? 2) im not getting the output i would expect for this program I thought it would produce 100 buttons all the same size but the first row of buttons are smaller than the rest?

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep` on the Swing event thread only puts your entire application to sleep, meaning no drawing, nothing gets done. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: As for debugging, add break points in critical parts of code.

Comment: Is there a analogue of the method Tread.sleep using Swing Timer . Do i have to write a actionpeform method? Also the top layer of buttons are slightly smaller than the rest?

Comment: Read the link as it explains how the timer works and what it does. And don't set sizes. Let the layout managers take care of that.